# Why isn't the data frame output grouped by school_code?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I am having an issue with outputting summarized values in a table that is grouped by column "school_code". I am not sure what went wrong? I simply want to calculated number of occurrences (n) and percentage (%) and compile it in a df/table. Let me know if there is an easier way for me to do this any help is welcome! For reference I am using R.

Here is the data I am working with called "studyprogressraw":

| school | interview_status | grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

My code:

```
interviews_completed <- study_progress_raw %>%
  filter(ma_interview_status == 1) %>% 
  group_by(school_code) %>%
  mutate(num_row = n()) %>%
  mutate(percent = (num_row / sum(num_row)) * 100) %>%
  summarise(
    Interviews_Completed = paste0(num_row, " (", percent, ")")
  )
```

What I want:

| school_code | Interviews_Completed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 (50) |
| 10 | 1 (100) |
| 15 | 1 (100) |

What I got:

| school_code | Interviews_Completed |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 (50) |
| 1 | 2 (50) |
| 10 | 1 (100) |
| 15 | 1 (100) |

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? I grouped by school_code so I assumed it would just aggregate by that column.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `count`

```
library(dplyr)

study_progress_raw %>% 
  filter(interview_status == 1) %>% 
  count(school) %>% 
  mutate(n = paste0(n, " (", 100/n, ")"))
```

```
 school       n
1      1  2 (50)
2     10 1 (100)
3     15 1 (100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put everything inside the `summarise` function. `mutate` will return a new column the length of the dataframe, whereas `summarise` returns a dataframe that is only as long as the number of groups.

```r
interviews_completed <- study_progress_raw %>%
  filter(interview_status == 1) %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarise(
    Interviews_Completed = paste0(n(), " (", (n()/sum(n())*100), ")")
  )
```

**EDIT:** If you do want to keep the extra columns you created:

```r
interviews_completed <- study_progress_raw %>%
  filter(interview_status == 1) %>%
  group_by(school) %>%
  summarise(
    num_row = n(),
    percent = (num_row / sum(num_row)) * 100,
    Interviews_Completed = paste0(num_row, " (", percent, ")")
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the behavior of `summarise()` after dplyr 1.0.0, see [this article](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/) for more information. And I believe after dplyr 1.1.0, this usage of `summarise()` will signal a warning:

```bash
Warning message:
Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()` always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

You could try this:

```r
interviews_completed <- study_progress_raw %>%
  filter(ma_interview_status == 1) %>% 
  group_by(school_code) %>%
  mutate(num_row = n()) %>%
  mutate(percent = (num_row / sum(num_row)) * 100) %>%
  summarise(
    Interviews_Completed = paste0(unique(num_row), " (", unique(percent), ")")
  )
```